# LyX: Как пользоваться тезаурусом?

Tags: lyx

В программе LyX в меню *Инструменты* есть команда *Тезаурус*. Не подскажите, как ей пользоваться?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы по сто раз не набирать, скопирую ответ со своего блога.

Тезаурус выдает синонимы к выделенному слову. Его настройка в LyX осуществляется следующим образом. Скачиваем [отсюда](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N_IOaMMbN7lLIr5UMfESl2xgF0DgYRL-) архив (это для версии 2.0.6, с другими версиями не знаю, будет-нет работать), копируем его содержимое в папку `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\thes`. Лично я после этого LyX не перезапускал, но всякое может быть... Все, в окне LyX выделяем слово (это делается так: курсор подводится к началу(окончанию) интересующего слова, нажимается левая кнопка мышки, и, не отпуская кнопки, двигаем мышку к окончанию(началу) интересующего слова, после того, как последняя(первая) буква интересующего слова оказывается выделенной, отпускаем левую кнопку мыши. А можно и так: курсор подводится к началу(окончанию) интересующего, нажимаются и удерживаются сразу 2 клавиши <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> и <kbd>Shift</kbd>, а потом стрелка влево (стрелка вправо)), нажимаем Инструменты> 
Тезаурус или после выделения интересующего слова нажимаем и удерживаем <kbd>Shift</kbd>, а потом <kbd>F7</kbd>. Появляется окошечко, в нижней части которого и вместе с тем несколько выше кнопки <kbd>Отменить</kbd> содержатся синонимы к выделенному интересующему слову, связанные термины с выделенным словом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(снимок сделан после щелчка левой кнопкой мышки по слову *репутация*). Если мы в данной ситуации нажмем кнопку <kbd>Заменить</kbd>, слово *Популярность* в окне LyX заменится словом *репутация*. После окончания работы с тезаурусом, закрываем диалоговое окно "Lyx: Тезаурус" или нажимаем в этом диалоговом окне кнопку <kbd>Отменить</kbd>. Если мы используем кнопку <kbd>Отменить</kbd>, произведенная нами ранее замена выделенного в окне LyX слова с помощью Тезауруса НЕ ОТМЕНЯЕТСЯ! Так, ну, вроде, это все, что я хотел сообщить по этому поводу.